# Save h:outputFormat result to a variable

Tags: jsp, variables, jsf, outputformat

Currently I am successfully getting the labels from my resource bundle via

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{labels['key']}">
   <f:param value="my param1"/>
   <f:param value="my param2"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

But how do I save it in a variable so that I can use it inline like

```
<i data-original-title="#{myLabel}"></i>
```

I am looking for something like

```
<h:outputFormat var="myLabel" value="#{labels['key']}">
   <f:param value="my param1"/>
   <f:param value="my param2"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Comment: What output your got?

Comment: That last code block does not save anything to any var.

Comment: How should it save something? It’s an outputFormat and simply [renders parameterized text](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets).

Comment: Yeah, thus the line "I am looking for something LIKE", because I know it doesn't work and I want to know something that works. Atleast that's what I tried so far :)

Comment: Why don’t you simple use MessageFormat and format it in your bean?

Comment: We are not using managed beans as we are integrating JSF and Spring and we are only using JSF on the front-end.

Comment: But you are accessing SpringBeans in your Facelets? If not you could use MessageFormat, add the result to the request or session and access it via #{param} or #{session}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Omnifaces extension of `outputFormat`:
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat